# Damping factor - loudspeakers and headphones

Tags: electromagnetism

Is there any specific reason why speaker's impedance is taken into account in the damping factor formula?

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping_factor) explains pretty well why low output impedance of an amplifier gives more damping, it all makes sense. But how can higher impedance speakers result in more damping? Is there more damping force? Or is it just all about determining whether output impedance is negligible with respect to loudspeaker's impedance? It's really hard to find anything on the subject except the raw definition of dampening factor.

In short: why using high impedance speakers results in more damping?

Answer (score 1):

'Damping factor' is *defined* as the ration of speaker impedance to output impedance. So, higher speaker impedance, more damping.

It's a fairly meaningless concept and indeed a pretty meaningless number by itself, especially as it is invariably referred to 8 ohms instead of an actual speaker impedance. The real item of interest is the amplifier's output impedance, and its variance with frequency. The lower the internal output impedance, the more effect negative feedback can have on unwanted currents appearing across the load impedance due to speaker non-linearity, flyback, reverse EMF etc.

Comment: Then why isn't it defined as one divided by output impedance? They must have had a reason to put speaker's impedance there. And I'm trying to find out why using higher impedance speakers with the same amplifiers results in better control over undesirable coil movements etc.

Comment: Good question. The case you mention where it is measured against a real load impedance is the useful case; the case where measured against 8 ohms, a resistance not an impedance, isn't.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that the "ideal" amplifier is a constant voltage source with an output resistance near 0. A high loudspeaker resistance will give better operating conditions for the amplifier's feedback system in order to maintain the constant voltage. But as you may well know there is nothing about this that is constant nor ideal. You shouldn't pay too much attention to the damping factor because it is very unpredictable. Real world speaker impedances does not even resemble the nominal input resistance. If you were to simulate both the amplifier and loudspeaker in great detail you would perhaps be able to say something about the damping factor, but then you would also realize how of little interest it really is.